# Enabling both permalinks and extensionless php routing not working in Nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, permalinks

I have my `nginx.conf` file as follows:

```
server {
    ...    
root /var/www/html;

            # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
            index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

            server_name mydomain.com;

            if (!-e $request_filename)
            {
             rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
            }


            location / {

                    try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
            }


            location ~ \.php$ {
                    try_files $uri =404;
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            }

            location @extensionless-php {
                    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
            }
}
```

I have WordPress installed on Nginx in Ubuntu server running.

I have a navigation menu named Resume that leads to [example.com/resume](http://example.com/resume) and shows a pdf file that is actually **myname_resume.pdf** but I have putted **resume.php** in the root directory and this php script gets the contents of **myname_resume.pdf** and displays it as pdf file.

I want my url never append any file extension **.pdf** or **.php** no matter if you anyone can expicitily write url.php and it would give the same result and hence I had done this. This configuration of `extensionless-php` was working fine when I putted this code:

```
if (!-e $request_filename)
{
    rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
}
```

As I have WordPress installed, I wanted to give permalink to a page created on WordPress as [example.com/contact](http://example.com/contact) and for enabling permalink, I had to add above small configuration. Now the permalink is opening but the mydomain.com/resume is giving 404 error. How to enable both of them or is there any good method to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than appending the `.php` to any non-existent files - you could change the logic so that the `.php` is appended to the URI only if a PHP file actually exists.

For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    if (-f $request_filename.php) {
        rewrite ^ $uri.php last;
    }
    rewrite ^ /index.php last;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.